# Getting Delete Icon to Display on Same Line as Email Address

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, less

I have some UI in my Angular app where, next to an email link, I have a delete icon which users can use to delete an email. The delete icon is designed to display only when the email is being hovered over. This is all working as expected.

However, for some reason the delete icon is showing on the line below the actual email. I've tried various configurations - both in my LESS/CSS, and in my HTML, to get the email and the delete icon to show on the same line, to no avail. I also tried wrapping in a span, still didn't work.

Also, to clarify, there is plenty of room in the containing div, so that's not the issue. The most recent thing I tried, as you'll see in my code below, is to add "display: inline" to the class being called from the main div. But again, it's not working.

Here's what my template code looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let email of staff?.emails; let i = index;" class="email-section" [hoverOverFor]="emailRemove">

        <a class="email-display" [href]="'mailto:'+staff.email" title="Email">{{staff.email}}</a> 

             <div #emailRemove hover-content>
                  <button class="email-remove" md-icon-button (click)="removeEmail(i)">
                        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                  </button>
             </div>
</div>
```

And my LESS/CSS looks like this:

```
.email-section {
  display: inline;
}

.email-remove {
  opacity: 0.5;
  &:hover
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.email-display {
  .flex-col;
  .justify-content-center;
}
```

How can I adjust my LESS/CSS to get the email address and delete icon to display on the same line?

Comment: You can set `display: inline;` on this div ' <div #emailRemove hover-content>'.
`.email-display + div {display: inline;}`

Comment: could you create a reproduction?

Comment: AndreiC, I tried that, still didn't work.

Comment: Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bbdjvg90/ ... anyway LiHRaM also works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally understand how that can be frustrating, but it seems like a simple problem. Is there perhaps a reason you don't want to use `float:left`?

Otherwise, that is the ideal solution.
See the following jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hwog55p9/)

```
.email-display {
  float:left;
  .flex-col;
  .justify-content-center;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: For the most part this worked, thanks. Just had to add some additional padding to line things up. Still don't quite understand why adding the float:left was necessary, though. Any thoughts on the rule here?

Comment: @Muirik - Necessary, as opposed to `display:inline`?
Well, I'm not entirely sure. 
I know that the default behavior of a div is block - filling the entire width of the parent, and by simply setting it to float left you change that behaviour.
Andrei C also commented a version in which you can set both the anchor and the divider elements to `display:inline`, but `float:left` seemed an easier option.